# How to format a Date to a specific format on Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I must format a object created by `Date()` to a especific format, this format must show the date like:

`28 may, 2018 11:00:32`

I've a func to make the formatation of `Date()`, but to the follow format:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Function working:

```
static func dateFormatTime(date : Date) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

But I don't know how make on this format: `dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: You really shouldn't make your date a specific format. Use date and time styles so the date appears properly to all users of your app no matter where they live.

Comment: [NSDateFormatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com) is your friend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply, all you have to do is to change the `dateFormatter.dateFormat` value to the desired format, which is **"dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss"** in your case:

```
func dateFormatTime(date : Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

therefore:

```
let str = dateFormatTime(date: Date())
print(str) // 29 May, 2018 12:18:08
```

**Time zone:**

You could also set the desired time zone like this:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
```

---

### Update:

Thanks for [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) for suggesting using date styles ([`dateStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415411-datestyle) and [`timeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413467-timestyle) properties) instead of editing the date format.

> When displaying a date to a user, you set the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`
> properties of the date formatter according to your particular needs... Based on the values of the `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties, `DateFormatter` provides a representation of a specified date that is appropriate for a given locale.
>
> <sub>[DateFormatter - Working With User-Visible Representations of Dates and Times.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)</sub>

Hence:

```
func dateFormatTime(date : Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
    
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
 
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}

let str = dateFormatTime(date: Date())
print(str) // May 29, 2018 at 12:45:08 AM
```

Comment: I use Locale to set my time zone, but the time is wrong. And, how I set date on format 00:00 -> 23:59? The way it is 00:00->11:59.

Comment: @Augusto answer updated.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `MM` is the month, `mm` is minutes. `hh` is a 12-hour time and should always be used with `a`. Better yet, do not use a `dateFormat`. Use styles.

Comment: now is : `21:16`, but the code returns : `28 mai, 2018 09:05:14`.You know why hh:MM is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the note @rmaddy, I did the mistake of "MM" for the minutes  because I just copied the desired format from the question without editing it. "Use styles" do you mean date and time styles?

Comment: Thank you very much.. all works done now.

Comment: @Augusto Yes, `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. It's poor practice to use `dateFormat` to show a date to a user.

Comment: @rmaddy answer updated, hope it is better for now . Again, thanks for the kind information in advance.